# Get exact width element

Tags: javascript

I have an element with 80.5px width

in javascript i have a script that checks whats the elements width is

```
document.getElementById("..").clientWidth
```

but that returns 80 and not 80.5 is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @DavidThomas i dont have any code that can be shown since i use react and an api so i have to show u very much code, maybe i can explain it a little better: 
When i inspect my site, an specific element has a width of 80.5px but my script returns 80px

Comment: @DavidThomas *An element cannot be 80.5px wide once rendered to the screen.* It can very well be, and it's also a visible difference on devices with a device-to-pixel ratio > 1.

Comment: @connexo, I guess I can see that with with higher device resolutions, but I hadn't really thought about it before. Thanks for the update, I get to live and learn a little more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve by using `Element.getBoundingClientRect().width`

```js
let box = document.getElementById('box');
let width = box.getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log(width);
```

```css
#box { width:80.5px; }
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```